# Silence then restart onTouchListener

Tags: android

I have an `onTouchListener` that will record the coordinates of a touchpoint, but will then silence after the coordinates of the touchpoint are stored as variable `var1`. After this, I would like to start another `onTouchListener` which will record the coordinates of the next touchpoint, and store them as variable `var2`. I attempted this as shown in the following `.java` file:

`.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);
        final TextView item1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item1);
        final TextView item2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item2);

        \\First onTouchListener Begins
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Integer var1x = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                Integer var1y = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY());
                item1.setText("Touch coordinates : " + touchvar1x + " x " + touchvar1y);

                touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
                return true;

                }
                }); 

        \\Second onTouchListener Begins         
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Integer var2x = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                Integer var2y = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY());
                item2.setText("Touch coordinates : " + touchvar2x + " x " + touchvar2y);

                touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
                return true;

                }
                }); 
        }       


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

}
```

As you can see, my attempt was to simply silence then start another onTouchListener. However, this causes the first onTouchListener to not work at all. Is there a reason why this is happening, and is it possible to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have two events that need to occur, maybe it would be best just to add a boolean expression inside the first listener and remove the second listener all together.

Something along the lines of this:

```
touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(!userTouchedOnce){
            Integer var1x = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
            Integer var1y = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY());
            item1.setText("Touch coordinates : " + touchvar1x + " x " + touchvar1y);

            userTouchedOnce = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Integer var2x = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
            Integer var2y = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY());
            item2.setText("Touch coordinates : " + touchvar2x + " x " + touchvar2y);
        }
        return true;

    }
});
```

//EDIT - You asked for a way to do three events.

`int touchNumber = 1;`

```
touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(touchNumber) {
          case 1:  Integer var1x = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                   Integer var1y = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY());
                   item1.setText("Touch coordinates : " + touchvar1x + " x " + touchvar1y);
                   touchNumber++;
                   break;
          case 2:  Integer var2x = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                   Integer var2y = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY());
                   item2.setText("Touch coordinates : " + touchvar2x + " x " + touchvar2y);
                   touchNumber++;
                   break;
          case 3: // Do something else.
                   break;
          default: break;
        }

        return true;

    }
});
```

Comment: Cool idea, do you know how I could expand this for 3 instead of 2?